# Не работает collectstatic

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь собрать все статические ресурсы. Делаю следующее:

1. Запускаю виртуальную среду
2. Указываю `python manage.py collectstatic`

Получю ошибку:

> ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and
>   available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to
>   activate a virtual environment?

Не совсем понятно, почему эта ошибка выскакивает. Помогите советом, пожалуйста.

P. S. 
листинг `pip list` выдает следующее:

```
cffi (0.8.6)
chardet (2.3.0)
colorama (0.3.2)
cryptography (0.6.1)
dnspython (1.12.0)
html5lib (0.999)
ndg-httpsclient (0.3.2)
pip (9.0.1)
ply (3.4)
pyasn1 (0.1.7)
pycparser (2.10)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
pyinotify (0.9.4)
pyOpenSSL (0.14)
python-apt (0.9.3.12)
requests (2.4.3)
setuptools (5.5.1)
six (1.8.0)
urllib3 (1.9.1)
virtualenv (15.1.0)
wheel (0.24.0)
```

В листинге нет Django, но физически он присутсвует в site-packages. да и сам сайт-то работает. И админка тоже работает. Как такое может быть?

```
Python 2.7.9. Django 1.11
```

Comment: Либо вы не запустили виртуальное окружение, либо не установили в него Django.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev

Сергей, я же написал. Виртуальное окружение запущено. Django установлен

Comment: Покажите вывод `pip list`

Comment: Проверьте каталог через который обращаетесь к manage.py

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Обновил информацию. Добавил вывод с pip list. Теперь еще чудесатее стало. Django присутствует, сайт рботает. Доступ в админку есть. Все материалы, заносимые через админку сохраняются в БД. Но в листинге его (Django) нет. Как такое может быть?